# Get injection point / injection target with Angular DI

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm looking for a way to get information about the object something is injected into with Angular DI. Something like `InjectionPoint` known from [CDI](http://www.cdi-spec.org/).

In the Java dependency injection framework *CDI* (which is actually only a spec) there is a pretty cool feature with which you can get information about the [injection point](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_the_injectionpoint_object) in a factory.

Example from the Weld (a CDI implementation) documentation:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

class LogFactory {
   @Produces Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
      return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
   }
}
```

In this case `InjectionPoint` is used to create a logger for the specific class to be instantiated.

I want to do something similar in Angular. Depending on the concrete target class I want to inject some configuration data.

How can I achieve this with Angular?

Comment: You might be able to do what you need with a custom decorator.. depends on your exact requirements

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm looking for the exact same thing right now

Comment: Sadly I didn't find a solution to this problem.